# Animate an element in real time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I need to know the position of an img in real time in order to change its position while is going up or down. The target is animate it to the bottom 40px at the beginning and animate it to the top later.

My code up to now is the following:

```
var pos = $('header img').offset().top;

if( pos == 0) {
   $('header img').animate({"top": "+=40px"}, 6000);
}else{
    $('header img').animate({"top": "-=40px"}, 6000);
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: what means exactly `in order to change its position while is going up or down` ? Also what are you seeking? to loop it's movement? or simply upon some event (like `click`) to set/reset the final position?

Comment: cause without seeing the rest of your code or at least knowing your intent `pos > 0` and inverting your `+-` would suffice.

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan My intention is to simulate an automatic animation for a background image like this: [link](http://visiologic.net/en/index.html) with a single image and in both directions, up and down.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `progress` option to detect the position live. I also made some changes so you don't have to use so much duplicated code:

```
$('#startAnimation').on('click', function () {
    var pos = $('header #img').offset().top;

    if (pos == 0) {
        doAnimate("+=40px");
    } else {
        doAnimate("-=40px");
    }
});

function doAnimate(to) {   
    $('header #img').animate({
        top: to
    }, {
        duration: 6000,
        progress: function (promise) {
            console.log('offset top: ' + $('header #img').offset().top);
        }
    });
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z3jk1g0z/

You could  also change it to use `start` and `complete` options in `animate`. More information: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

**EDIT:** wrong Fiddle

Comment: Great, didn't know the progress option. Thanks a lot.

Comment: So this what you were looking for?